# how to turn a php session into a usable variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session

i have created a site were i have 2 tables on a database. the first page has 2 links which when clicked sends the name of the link to a php session. it then takes you to a page were its meant to view ether one of the databases based on the data that has been saved In the php session.

what i am trying to achieve is to have those links open up the table inside that file that will open up when the link is clicked. i don't want to make a new .php file for every table since i want to be able to simply add and access those tables on one document but not more then one.

that is my problem. on that document were it sends me to access the table from my database i want to access in variable (code below). the code below will explain what i need to know.

this is the code which i view the data in my table

```
 $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "myDB";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM tablenamehere  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<p>". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "</p>";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
```

>
the code below is were i want to have the variable that has the name of the link i clicked on the page which gets redirected to this when the link is clicked. the variable that i gather from the php session i want to appear at the tablenamehere text.

```
 $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM tablenamehere  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

the code i have so far which creates the php session but is not connected to links yet are below.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="test1.php?a=newtable">Register Now!</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php

session_start();
?>

<?php
 if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    $_SESSION['link']=$_GET['a'];
 }

 echo "the veriable is " . $_SESSION['link'] . "<br>";
```

i only want multiple tables to open up in this one php file. thank you for helping, any questions please message below.

Comment: Just to correctly understand, what you are trying to achieve is showing the table by clicking the link without a redirect to another page?

Comment: no it redirects to another page but on that redirected page i want to show multiple tables not all at once but the table that appears will depend on the link which is clicked. but i don't want to have seperate files for different tables. so i want to use php sessions to save the name of the link that is clicked the name of that link is the name of the table and i want that table to load up on the file which opens the tables. @uruloke. if you need to ask any more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Just read your session in your other file, you can read the session again in the same way as you did on the page where you created the session. (remember to do the session_start() first.

Comment: IMHO it would be a good idea to describe us the flow of steps more precisely, so we can understand which link / redirection calls what script. Until now we have not seen a redirection in your code, just links to be clicked by the user.

Comment: @hherger whats the difference from a link and redirection. my link is redirecting the page to another page when the link is clicked or am i wrong. (i think I'm wrong)

Comment: Link, hyperlink: _<a href="&hellip;">_ that is clicked by the user. Redirection: a header _header("location: url..")_ that is sent by a script to the browser which automatically calls the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: the script that accesses the database is `test1.php`. The link adds already the call parameter `a` (=newtable):

> ```
> <a href="test1.php?a=newtable">Register Now!</a>
> ```

The script `test1.php` could honor this `$_GET` parameter like you do when setting the `$_SESSION` parameter. The modification of your code would then look like this:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Get and sanitize table name
$tablename = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['a']);

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM $tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// ....
```

### Notes:

- In my example I assume that all tables are handled the same way. Of course, you could differentiate code based on the value of *`$tablename`*.
- You most probably would **not need** a `$_SESSION` variable.
- If, for any reason you **must** use a `$_SESSION` variable `$_GET['a']` obviously should be overwritten by `$_SESSION['link']` or vice-versa.
- > For security reasons, **do not forget to sanitize the input parameter `$_GET['a']`!**

Comment: would i have to add the <?php
 if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    $_SESSION['link']=$_GET['a'];
 }

Comment: If I understand you right, you would not even need $_SESSION for the $_GET parameter "a" would be sent every time the link is clicked. You just would have to make sure the "a" parameter has the right value.

Comment: what do you mean about the "a" parameter having the right value.

Comment: these are on seperate pages and its still not loading up.

Comment: My assumption is that the user (always) clicks a link like "<a href="test1.php?a=newtable">Register Now!</a>" with the appropriate parameter "a=table_name" set. (Probably you are generating this link by a PHP script too.).

Comment: If an intermediate script (by redirection) gets control, this script obviously would habe to forward the "a" parameter to the "test1.php" script.

Comment: this is just a link on my server to another page but i want to use sessions to save name newtable and enter it were it says table name here so it responds with the corresponding table to that name but it doesn't seam to be working.

Comment: If you need to store values from one step to another, I'd prefer $_SESSION variables (server-side cookies) vs. client-side cookies for security reasons. My guess is that you would not need either. Which component is creating the _<a href="test1.php?a=newtable">Register Now!</a>_ link?

Comment: it is a link from my database if that is what you mean is a component

Comment: With "component" I meant the script that generates this html code. This component - of course - should set the "a" variable properly.

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume you are passing a table name as a parameter ( bit dangerous ) then you can do this

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    $_SESSION['link']=$_GET['a'];
}


$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname 
        FROM {$_SESSION['link']}
        ORDER BY id 
        DESC LIMIT 500";
```

But a better way might be to pass an indicator to the table you want to use. This way you are not passing a real table name around in the ether for people to see

```
if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    $_SESSION['link']=$_GET['a'];
}


switch ($_SESSION['link']) {
case : 'a'
    $tbl_name = 'table1';
    break;
case : 'b'
    $tbl_name = 'table2';
    break;
default:
    $tbl_name = 'default_table';
}


$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname 
        FROM $tbl_name 
        ORDER BY id 
        DESC LIMIT 500";
```

Comment: Please explain to OP why your other solution might be an better way to do it.

Comment: thanks. on my website i have a page were you add new tables. and the page with links is the page were those tables get shown i want to access those tables in one document but only one table at a time which is determined by the link which is clicked. if this helps.

Comment: Then I think this should help you. But I am not sure why you want to use the session as using just the `$_GET['a']` would do. Although you will need to sanitize that variable as someone could pass anything in that parameter